# How to get django-ezviews up and running

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am having trouble understanding how to get [django-ezviews](https://github.com/noirbizarre/django-eztables/) working. I have a class based view in my views.py file, but it isn't returning any data from my model, or rendering. I keep getting the error: `type object 'datatablesTestView' has no attribute 'asView'`

Models.py

```
class IPED(models.Model):
    unitid = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    instnm = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    addr = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    zipcode = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    census = models.CharField(max_length=120)
```

views.py

```
class datatablesTestView(DatatablesView):
    model = IPED

    fields = (
        'unitid',
        'instnm',
        'city',
        'state',
        'census',
    )
```

urls.py

```
from tracker_app.views import datatablesTestView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'tracker_app.views.index', name='index'),
    url(r'^test/$', datatablesTestView.asView(),name="datatables test"),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python uses `snake_case` for naming things, not `camelCase`, among other things pointed out in [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

You are calling `asView`, but you should really be calling `as_view`.